# What happens when two jobs produce artifacts with conflicting locations?

Tags: gitlab

In my GitLab CI log I pipeline with three stages

1. `build` creates a distribution
2. `semantic-release` which bumps the version
3. `publish`

The problem occurs in `publish`. Sometimes I see the version unbumped. You can see here that `semantic-release` has the higher number 148288 and it's running BEFORE `build` which overwriting the files. This means this job results in failure,

```
Downloading artifacts for semantic-release (148288)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=148288 responseStatus=200 OK token=xFzfAzW6
Downloading artifacts for build (148285)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=148285 responseStatus=200 OK token=zxTTXZoA
```

But sometimes the same pipeline elsewhere is succeeding,

```
Downloading artifacts for build (113579)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=113579 responseStatus=200 OK token=Cfqjv8bG
Downloading artifacts for semantic-release (113665)...
Downloading artifacts from coordinator... ok        id=113665 responseStatus=200 OK token=GAyN8S9M
```

Notice on this one the `build` job comes before `semantic-release`. That means the older artifacts are replaced. What happens if the artifact in `semantic-release` and `build` conflict by path? Is this defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [Bug #324412](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/324412)

With the bug, basically the rule of thumb is this,

> A job can rely on an artifact produced by a previous job only so long as no jobs previous to that one produced the same artifact.

The bug report suggests using [`dependencies`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/job_artifacts.html) to only download specific artifacts.